# sed removes newline at EOF

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I've tried using `sed` to replace an `SELECT` with `BELECT` in a file:

```
sed 's/SELECT/BELECT/g' add_pixel.sql | diff - add_pixel.sql
```

Gives me:

```
22c22
<   BELECT MAX(ID) INTO max_id FROM pixels;
---
>   SELECT MAX(ID) INTO max_id FROM pixels;
36c36
<       '(BELECT id FROM pixels WHERE pixel_id=''', new_pixel_id,
---
>       '(SELECT id FROM pixels WHERE pixel_id=''', new_pixel_id,
47c47
< DELIMITER ;
---
> DELIMITER ;
\ No newline at end of file
```

This was confirmed by `wc` - the fiel after `sed` is one line shorter than the original.

Why did sed's `'s/SELECT/BELECT/g'` removed the newline from the last line of the file?

Comment: This does not happen to me. Can you pastebin the `add_pixel.sql` file for further testing?

Comment: Strange. The only place it happens is OSX Bash, can't duplicate on Ubuntu either. Can anyone move this to askdifferent.stackexchange please?

Comment: Are you asking a migration? If yes, You can delete the question and re-ask at askdifferent.stackexchange.com . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your sql file that's missing the newline. `sed` was "nice" and made sure its output had a trailing newline.

```
$ diff <(printf 'x') <(printf 'x\n')
1c1
< x
\ No newline at end of file
---
> x

$ diff <(printf 'x\n') <(printf 'x')
1c1
< x
---
> x
\ No newline at end of file
```

Notice how the "\ No newline..."-line is positioned according to which file was missing it.